# Get sub part of HTML code in jquery (match entire paragraphs instead of line by line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, regex

I make an ajax call from jquery to obtain entire html of a page. I now want to extract a sub section of this html code between String 1 and String 2. I tried using regex but it matches line by line hence returns null for :

```
data.match(new RegExp("String 1(.*)String 2"));
```

What can I use to match entire paragraph since the two Strings are present in different lines and I want the part between these 2 lines.

Comment: Don't use `RegExp` to grab stuff from HTML. Use `document.createElement` and `insertAdjacentHTML` for this to render the page in memory and then use `DOM`-functions to get the stuff you need.

Comment: When using bash I used to run `sed -n -e '/String 1/,/String 2/ p'` to get the part between string 1 and string 2. Isn't there a corresponding alternative in jquery?

Comment: Yes there is, but HTML is very complex and regex are not really suited for this job.

Comment: Additionally, I don't wish to create HTML elements. I have fetched HTML from a url through ajax and I need to obtain some data from that. So what you are suggesting does not apply to my case

Comment: You are only creating them in memory, and it is a sturdier way to get results that match your expectation. Look for other solutions ons this case, you'll find similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

An example of my comment:

```js
var data = '<html><head></head><body><p>1 and it could span multiple lines.</p><p>2 and it could span multiple lines.</p></body>';

//create an container element in memory
var container = document.createElement("div");

//serialize the HTML into the container
container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", data);

//grab the paragraphs using querySelector
var pars = container.querySelectorAll("p");

//loop the nodelist with Array's forEach
Array.prototype.forEach.call(pars, function(element){
  console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

Comment: I can't just grab a particular tag because the HTML is vast and I need some very specific data. The only way to narrow down on that data is to use string 1 and string 2 because these are the only ever present things and give me accurate sub section. To get my data from that subsection would be easy. Problem is obtaining this subsection

Comment: Well that's why you serialize so you can get the subsections. Also if we don't know the structure we can't help you any further.

Comment: I don't see why the structure is so important. It's just an ordinary HTML code in text format stored in a variable. And my question is just that if instead of getting a sub string out of a string can I fetch a sub part out of the HTML code. Consider this as fetching a sub paragraph out of a full paragraph.